# C++ Segmentation fault - messages between 2 applications

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, message, corba, tao

I have 2 different applications, a sender and a receiver. the Sender will send a message over to the receiver, who will decode the message and print to the console. However, I keep getting segmentation fault error.

Both sender and receiver application have the same TestContainer.h and TestContainer.cpp.

Casting method

```
template<class To,class From>To cast(From v)
{
        return static_cast<To>(static_cast<const void*>)(v);
}
```

Sender application

```
int main()
{
    TestContainer tc;
    tc.setDesc("this is a message");
    const char* castedData = cast<const char*>(&tc);

    const TestContainer test_tc = cast<const TestContainer*>(castedData);

    // i get back "this is a message",so the casting is working
    cout << "message content: " << test_tc->getDesc() <<endl;

    TaoSender;      
    TaoSender.send(castedData);     

    return 1;
}
```

Receiver Application

```
void push(const RtecEventComm::EventSet& events)
{
    const char* receivedData;
    events[0].data.any_value >>= receivedData;

    cout << "data received: " << receivedData << endl;

    const TestContainer rcv_tc = cast<const TestContainer*>(receivedData);

    cout << "message content: " << rcv_tc->getDesc() <<endl; // error(segmentation fault)
}
```

TestContainer.h and TestContainer.cpp

```
class TestContainer{
    public 
        TestContainer();
        virtual ~TestContainer();
        const std:string& getDesc () const {
            return desc;
        }
        void setDesc(const std::string& desc) {
            this->desc = desc;
        }
    private
        std::string desc;
}



#include TestContainer.h

TestContainer::TestContainer(){}
TestContainer::~TestContainer(){}
```

The value of **castedData** at the sender and the value of **receivedData** at the receiver is the same, so I guess the message sending is correct.

However,at the **Receiver**, after converting the receivedData buffer to a Testcontainer pointer and attempting to access the desc, I get a segmentation fault error.

I also tried casting back to Testcontainer in the **Sender**, and I am able to access the desc. So what did I miss out?

Comment: You shouldn't cast the data, you cast a char* to a class, that is asking for problems.

Comment: This code has basic syntax errors eg `return static_cast<To>(static_cast<const void*)(v);` - missing ">" and misplaced parentheses. Please post actual code in a self contained example ([MCVE]).

Comment: This doesn't look at all like a CORBA program, check the examples and tests that are part of TAO

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen The TAO RtecEvent sending and receiving service is encapsulated by me, so if i send a simple string, float, or int value the receiver can receive the value perfectly,hence the messaging service is working. However, If i want to send a class (collection of attribute values), how should I send it? I do have over 40 classes,so I was hoping for an easy way to cast to a data stream.

Comment: You have to put the data yourself into for example a CORBA Any and send that. You just can't cast a class, TAO doesn't know how to marshal your types into a wire representation.

Comment: Or define all types in IDL and updated your application code to use the IDL generated types. Your example does use std::string, something which is not supported by TAO but is supported by the IDL to C++11 language mapping (which is way easier).

Answer (score 1):

Although the code in your question contains errors, if I understand you correctly you are trying to push the representation of an object over a pipe or other channel to another process, where you reconstruct the object and try to use it.

You could do this with "Plain Old Data" objects, but the `TestContainer` class has virtual methods and therefore it is not POD. In most implementations of C++, objects of type `TestContainer` will contain a vtable pointer which refers to a table allocated within the process' address space. The address of this table will likely be different in different processes. Therefore, copying the representation of the `TestContainer` object byte-by-byte to another process will lead to crashes when you try to call a virtual method.

`TestContainer` instances also contain a `std::string`. A `string` allocates storage to hold the string contents and this storage will be outside the objecet itself. Transmitting the byte representation of the `string` as part of `TestContainer` results in reconstruction at the other end of a `string` that holds a pointer to a memory address in another process. Within the receiver, that memory address will refer to something else. Hence, the `string` will not be successfully reconstructed.

To send objects between processes you need to properly transmit them in a form that is independent of memory addresses contained within (whether that be a vtable pointer, a pointer member, or a pointer member of a an opaque member such as a `string`). The process of converting data to such a form is called serialization. There are libraries available to assist with this, but nothing in the standard library.